# Unknown Publisher when I install application I wrote?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installation

When I install my application on my computer I get a warning that the publisher is not verified.  How can I change that? or do I need to worry about that when I distribute my application?

The application is written in Visual Studio 2008 with VB.NET

Answer (score 6):

On the Project Properties window, go to the Signing tab. Create/Import certificates and sign the manifests and/or assembly.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx), with helpful links at the "See Also" section.

Comment: There is no option in Visual Studio to sign setup projects. The link you referenced is for signing assemblies/executables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [signtool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command line program to sign exe files or msi files. I believe you might need a certificate from an official authority to change the UAC messages.